# when to use $rose system task with a signal in assertions

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I am trying to understand when to use `$rose` for a signal in assertion. For instance in what ways the two below assertions will behave differently?

```
first:assert property 
        (@(posedge clk) $rose(reset) |-> (data == 0));

second: assert property
          (@(posedge clk) reset |-> (data==0));
```

is it that `$rose` is to be used with asynchronous signals?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$rose` means that in the previous clock cycle the signal was '0' and in the current clock cycle it is '1'.

The first assertion will only check on the first cycle when `reset` goes high, whereas the second assertion will check that `data` is '0' in every clock cycle when `reset` is high.

Here's a nice drawing showing you when each of the assertions will trigger.

```
         _   _   _   _   _   _
clk    _| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_| |_
             ___________
reset  _____|           |_______

first           x   

second          x   x   x
```

`$rose` has meaning for synchronous signals.

Answer (score 0):

`$rose(reset)` works when there is transition from `0/x/z` to `1`, and will return `true` when there is such a transition.

`reset` without `$rose` **doesn't** account for this transition of `0/x/z` to `1`, and will return `false` when there is such a transition. Is this correct?

Answer (score -1):

$rose() is a system task that checks if the sampled value of the signal changed to 1 between previous sample and the current sample (Previous sample could be a 0/x/z).

it must to be two consecutive clock cycle sample.